# llvm load big structures

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm new to llvm IR and was wondering if you can use the `load` instruction to load relatively big structures. The documentation says something about restriction to `first class` types, however the sample code below compiled fine, will it also behave correctly?

```
%MyStruct = type { i32, i32, i64, i64 }

define void @my_func(%MyStruct *) local_unnamed_addr {
  %2 = load %MyStruct, %MyStruct* %0
  ret void
}
```

Comment: This mostly depends on the backend you are going to use. Pass your IR into `llc` tool get an assembler output and see if it suits you.

Comment: ok thanks! are there any guarantees if the structure contains only one integral element (such that the size would not be more than i64)?

Comment: any guarantees are defined by target ABI. Read a corresponding document for your target to find out all rules for passing structures by value.